# Is this quote really from the Rambam?

Tags: rambam, quotations

Some non-Jewish sources on the internet (eg [here](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/maimonides_184449)) attribute the following quote to the Rambam:

> Teach thy tongue to say, “I do not know,” and thou shalt progress

Does anyone have a source for this?

Comment: ברכות (דף ד', עמוד ב'): למד לשונך לומר איני יודע

Comment: Thank you @GershonGold! Looks like that quote was talking about deceit - not progress (https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.4a.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Also its the Gomorra, not Rambam. Do you know if Rambam ever used it in the context of making progress?

Comment: If the Rambam did say anything like that, I assume he meant you can only learn if you think you don't know.

Comment: A search on Sefaria for the Hebrew phrase quoted by @GershonGold doesn't turn up any results in Rambam.

Comment: it is mentioned twice in the commentary ON the Rambam called "Halacha L'Moshe"

Comment: @rosends can you link to that?

Comment: @N.T. so then there's a good chance the internet falsely attributed this. Who would've thought...

Comment: @dankmasterdan it came up in a Bar Ilan search. Unless I link to a screenshot of the search result, I'm not sure how to link to it.

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that this quote is in the Winter OU Jewish Action magazine (p. 105)?

Comment: @rosends you can either paste a screenshot in a full answer below, or just put the source in the Rambam?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/JFa8nrg